# Using extended access token without login

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I have converted my short-lived access-token into extended token i.e for 60 days. The token has permissions for publish_stream and publish_actions.

Can i use the graph API to post something on a facebook page without logging into facebook ? I only have extended token with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the access_token to make Graph API calls until the token expires.

An user access token becomes invalid after

```
2 hrs (if generated through client-side flow)
2 months (if generated through server-side flow)
Password change
De-authorization of app
```

Till it's valid, you can use it without asking the user to `log in`

Comment: Is it possible to extend token for 2 months through client-side (Javascript)

Comment: yes it's possible, but the endpoint requires you to input app_secret. that's why it's not recommended to extend it on client side.